# Assembly generation and types question

Tags: .net

My app generates a new type Foo and writes it to new assembly. Then I create an object of type Foo and serialize it. If I delete the assembly and recreate it when I try to deserialize the Foo object it tells me that cannot convert type Foo to type Foo. It thinks those are different types. Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: I have no control over the serialization.
EDIT: We found that the version guid is always different. What is this guid and how we can specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the module version id (MVID) is written in the serialization when you use binary formatter. When you want to deserialize it searches for the type in assembly with that MVID. Here is the bad. You do not have control over MVID. Here is the good. You can open the dll file, find and replace the MVID with yours. I tested that by changing the MVID with hex editor and it works.

Comment: 10x, that is exactly what we are going to do.

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix it would be to use XML serialization instead of binary serialization. Binary serialization with [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) emits type information and when the assembly is recreated it is no longer the same assembly (unless you ensure to have the exact same IL). Also if you are doing this in the same process (creating and deleting an assembly dynamically) note that because assemblies, once loaded, can **never** be unloaded from an AppDomain you might end up with the same assembly name loaded twice in the same AppDomain which is very bad and you will indeed have problems.

Comment: Pedant point; it is BinaryFormatter (et al) that include this - it is not an inbuilt trait of "binary serialization". Binary serializers exist that do not (mis)behave like this.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, good point, it is indeed the `BinaryFormatter` that behaves like this.

Comment: (I kinda get a bit sensitive about this ;p - perhaps overly so...)

Comment: @Marc Gravell, no, you are precise, that's exactly how all of us should be in this business. Programming is a precise science.

Comment: The problem is not in binary formatter. We need to fix the assembly creation. When deserialize with binary formatter it looks for the specific assembly with given guid. I expect other problems but we will handle them :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `BinaryFormatter`, right? there-in lies pain. Any contract-based serializer should be fine; `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, protobuf-net, `JavaScriptSerializer`, etc.

Otherise, you'll have to handle the AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event and/or provide a custom binder; lots of work.

Comment: true, binary formatter, We did custom binding to tell where is the assembly for our types, 4 loc. But when we diff the assemblies we got 3-4 differences. We do not know what they are